# Why will this test not run with sucker punch gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker, sucker-punch

The purpose of this code is to send an email to a user with an array of products whose discount percentages have reached a given threshold.  The products are returned by:

```
user.notifications
```

which returns an array of 2 element arrays with the following format:

```
[[product, notification]]
```

A notification is an object composed of a discount percentage and a product_id.

```
send_notification?
```

checks to see if a user has been sent a notification in the last 7 days and returns a boolean (true if they have not received an email in the last week and false if they have for the product being passed in.)

I have the following job and accompanying test:

```
class ProductNotificationEmailJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job

  def perform(user)
    user_notifications = user.notifications || []
    products = []
    notifications = []
    user_notifications.each do |notification|
      if notification[1].send_notification?
        products << notification[0]
        notifications << notification[1]
      end
    end
    NotificationMailer.notification_email(user, products).deliver

    notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update(notification_date: Time.now)
    end
  end
end
```

test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ProductNotificationEmailJob do
  it 'performs' do 
    notification = ObjectCreation.create_notification
    expect(notification.notification_date).to be_nil
    user = notification.user
    stub = double("Object")

    expect(NotificationMailer).to receive(:notification_email).with(user, [notification.my_product.product]).and_return(stub)

    expect(stub).to receive(:deliver)

    ProductNotificationEmailJob.new.perform(user)

    expect(MyProductsNotification.last.notification_date).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

When I take out the line:
     include SuckerPunch::Job 
the test passes fine but I cannot get it to pass with that line in though.  For some reason with the include SuckerPunch::Job line it seems as though the object creation method does not work and returns nil for all values.  I apologize in advance if I didn't give enough detail but I didn't want to post too much code.  Leave a comment and I will include any details requested.  Thank you for your time I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the problem with fresh eyes I realized I was violating encapsulation rules by even trying to do all of that stuff in the ProductNotificationEmailJob class.  I extracted into another class and everything runs fine and is perfectly testable.